# How to desearialise XML from a file to a collection of objects

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I have a vehicle class and I have created a collection of the vehicle classes `SelectedVehicle(10)` Depending on how many Vehicles in the XML I would like to add the XML to my class but in my objects the properties in my have the wrong amount of doors in each in this case one instance have 8 doors  and 8 windows when my XML has 4 in each object.

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Vehicles>
    <Vehicle Id="V9">
        <Doors>
             <Door>Door10</Door>
             <Door>Door11</Door>
             <Door>Door12</Door>
            <Door>Door13</Door>
        </Doors>
        <Windows>
            <Window Id="Win10">Window0</Window>
            <Window Id="Win11">Window1</Window>
            <Window Id="Win12">Window2</Window>
            <Window Id="Win13">Window3</Window>
        </Windows>
    </Vehicle>
    <Vehicle Id="V19">
        <Doors>
             <Door>Door10</Door>
             <Door>Door11</Door>
             <Door>Door12</Door>
            <Door>Door13</Door>
        </Doors>
        <Windows>
            <Window Id="Win10">Window0</Window>
            <Window Id="Win11">Window1</Window>
            <Window Id="Win12">Window2</Window>
            <Window Id="Win13">Window3</Window>
        </Windows>
    </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>
```

VBScript Code:

```vb
Class Vehicle
    Dim Doors(10)
    Dim Windows(10)
End Class

Sub LoadGame(ByRef selectedGame)
    Dim Root, NodeListr
    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXMLDoc.Async = False
    objXMLDoc.Load("C:\Audits.xml")

    For i = 0 To UBound(selectedVehicle)
        Set xmlVs = objXMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Door")

        For j = node To UBound(xmlVs)
            SelectedVehicle(i).Doors = handleNode(node)
        Next

        Set xmlWindows = _objXMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Window")

        Dim i : i = 0
        For f To UBound(xmlWindows)
            SelectedVehicle(i).Doors = handleNode(node)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function handleNode(node)
    For Each elem In node.ChildNodes
        Select Case node.TagName
            Case "Window"
                handleNode = elem.Text
            Case "Door"
                handleNode = elem.Text
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. Not only does it have several syntax errors, it also never instantiates the class or invokes the procedure `LoadGame`. Also, how do you associate the vehicle IDs from your XML with the objects in the `selectedVehicles` list?

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback will overlook it.

Comment: Ok I understood your feedback. even if I manage to get the xml data there is no way to query the object.

Comment: That depends. It's certainly possible to de-serialize your XML data into objects, but that might require a different approach and/or modifications to your class. Please take a step back and give us a broader picture. Where does the data come from, and what are the `Vehicle` objects used for? How are the `Doors` and `Windows` member variables going to be used?

Comment: I have created the xml on my local machine. After revisiting my attempt I realise neither My object or xml structure  is not well built. I would like to get the collection of vehicle in the xml into a object structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly de-serialize an XML data structure into objects your class definition must match the XML structure. Since the `<Vehicle>` nodes in your XML data have an `id` attribute as well as `<Doors>` and `<Windows>` collection child nodes your class definition should probably look somewhat like this:

```vb
Class Vehicle
    Public ID
    Public Doors
    Public Windows

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        Set Doors   = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        Set Windows = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can process your XML data like this:

```vb
Set vehicles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each n In objXMLDoc.SelectNodes("//Vehicle")
    Set v = new Vehicle

    v.ID = n.GetAttribute("Id")
    For Each cn In n.SelectNodes("./Doors/Door")
        v.Doors.Add cn.Text
    Next
    For Each cn In n.SelectNodes("./Windows/Window")
        v.Windows.Add cn.Text
    Next

    vehicles.Add v.ID, v
Next
```

Using `ArrayList` collections for the `Doors` and `Windows` members avoid the limitations of using a fixed size array. You could do this with plain VBScript arrays too, but it would require more code.

Using a dictionary for the vehicles allows accessing objects in that collection by ID.

Of course this is just a very minimalistic example. For instance, you may want to use actual properties instead of public member variables in your `Vehicle` class. You may also want to add validation and error handling routines.